# Create a class based on a variable

Tags: java, class, design-patterns

I have a base class Accounts, that handles all of the information and methods of basic account functions.  Then I have subclasses of Checkings and Savings to handle specific functions for the different classes.  I have an action listener that will add the account,

```
    addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // add the account
            //this is where I am stuck!
            Account account = new Savings(amount);

        }

    });
```

and based on a variable in a JComboBox I want to be able to differentiate what kind of class is created.

```
    //get the types of accounts
    ArrayList<String> accountTypes = Account.getAccountTypes();
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(accountTypes.toArray());
    contentPanel.add(box);
```

What can I do to better handle this?

Comment: Use [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: Use a simple `if` statement? If combobox value is this then create a new Savings object, else if combobox valus is that create a new Checking object.

Comment: Jesper, I am working on designing my software a little better, I know that a simple switch or if statement will work here, but I want to get in the habit of making it more maintainable.

Comment: the getAccountTypes actually accesses the enum. There is also an account for Cash, and I would like to eventually further add accounts as I build the app, so that is why I wanted to further avoid the if/else structure. Also i'm just not sure how to instantiating a new class without having to do an if/else structure. I'm going to see what I can do with the Factory Pattern though. Thanks Luiggi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this only in action listener just put there simple if/else or switch/case. If there is a chance that somewhere else you will need to create objects in similar way read about design patterns like Factory Method.